# error with t_boolean_and and isset

Tags: php, mysql, sql

trying to make it check first if the current account is actually the one that it's trying to delete.
keep getting error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ',' or ') on line 12.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id'] && $_SESSION['id'] == $_GET['id'])) { --line 12--

 if (isset($_GET['BookID']) && is_numeric($_GET['BookID']))
 {
 // get id value
 $BookID = $_GET['BookID'];
 // delete the entry
$sql = "DELETE FROM `tbl_booking` WHERE `BookID`={$BookID}";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
echo "Your booking has been cancelled.";
 }
 else
 // if id isn't set, or isn't valid, redirect back to view page
 {
echo "doesn't work";
header('location: dashboard.php');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing a `)` and there's an extra at the end:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && $_SESSION['id'] == $_GET['id']) { 
                    -----^                one less here-----^
```

Also, you're going to need single quotes around this parameter, unless it will always, always be an integer:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM `tbl_booking` WHERE `BookID`='{$BookID}'";
```

Comment: Thought it was this tbh, it seems to have fixed it. I think my actual problem is sending 2 values through the url of the previous page.
thanks.